# Can a number be partitioned into parts satisfying this condition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions, decimal-expansion, natural-numbers

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be distinct decimal digits, with $ab,cd,ef$ being two-digit numbers formed from these digits (so that, for example, $ab=10a+b$).

How may I prove that the expression $ab+cd+ef$ assumes all integer values between $69$ and $255$? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: 10(a+c+e)+b+d+f  (a+c+e) part can hold all values between 6 and 24. But I am not sure b+d+f can hold all values between 0 and 9.

Comment: and do you think to get the max value of what you wrote, should the greatest values be assigned to $a,c,e$ or $b,d,f$?

Comment: I didn't understand what you intend. I meant I don't know if we can ensure there will always remain figures that these sum can range from 0 to 9.

Comment: Could the numbers ab,cd and ef be negative? Apparently not all of them could be negative, so how many are allowed to be negative? what is the min. value of a,b,...etc. Is zero allowed?

Comment: Nope, ab cd and ef can't be negative. Yes, zero allowed but they have to be two digit-number so only last digit can be zero.

Comment: Could a,b,c...all be equal? Apparently not all of them could be 1, because the lower bound is not 3, so could we say they are not equal or is it that ab, cd and ef are not equal?

Comment: No, none figure that we assign to variables can be equal each other.

Comment: Please update the question with exact fact. "none of them" is vague. Please clearly state if a,b,c can't be equal or is it that ab,cd and ef can't be equal, or what the conditions are exactly!

Comment: I haven't noticed the rest of your comment, that's why i gave a short answer at first. Actually question has all statements that is needed to solve.

Comment: Do you have a problem with the solution presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that the question statement is accurate. Here is the best I could come up with.

Let K be a number satisfying:
$$K=ab+cd+ef$$
We want to prove:
$$K_{min}  <= K <= K_{max}$$

given that a,b,c,d,e,f are non zero, positive, non-duplicate. Also, ab,cd and ef are two digit numbers that is none of them is $<9$ (however, $10,11$, and $12$) is not valid because $a$, $c$ and $e$ would be equal.

$$K=(10a+b)+(10c+d)+(10e+f)$$
$$K=10(a+c+e)+(b+d+f)$$

Since a,b,c,d,e and f are different, positive, the minimum value for K would use {a,b,c,d,e,f}={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} in some order to get the minimum value of K.

To have a minimum value of K, we need the value of (a+c+e) to be minimum since it gets multiplied by 10. We choose $a=1,c=2,e=3$. We can choose the numbers b, d, f to be less than 9 and as small as possible.

We choose $b=4, d=5, f=0$ to get

$$K_{min}=10(1+2+3)+4+5+0=69$$

Please note that here we made the assumption that one of the 2nd digits could be zero (as in the case for 10+24+35 -See comment below).

To find the maximum value of $K$, we need to choose values of a,c and e as large as possible since their sum is multiplied by 10. We use $a=7, b=8, and c=9$. We choose $b, d , f$ as large as possible, so $b=6, d=5, f=4$.

$$K_{max}= 10(7+8+9)+6+5+4=255.$$

$$69<=K<=255$$

****Note:Thanks for user sulspatz for correcting an error in my answer****

Comment: Doesn't $10+24+35=69$ meet the conditions?

Comment: @saulspatz, you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But there is a question in my mind.  How K can hold all value in this range without problem. How we can make sure this without trying every number? I really don't understand but there is no problem with answer. Indeed problem is with me

Comment: Why would there be a problem with K? We can try each number through a program but you don't need to. The equation 10(a+c+e)+b+d+f in addition to the conditions you have provided are sufficient. I will be happy to clarify this solution more if you want.